# Python threading neither exiting nor 'threading'

Tags: python, multithreading

I tried to create a simple python script that has 2 main functions: Print something in a loop and wait for a keyboard interrupt to stop that loop.
I read about Threading and tried to test it out, but its not working for me.
Below is my code.
I create 2 Threads, one who prints something in a loop and the other one who waits for the exit command. 
I have 2 Problems in my code, and i don't know why:

First, the loop thread will not print anything until i hit enter for the other thread to finish. This also happens if i write the input function into the main program.

Second, even if i type in 100 and the program says "Exiting...", exittime will never be set to 1, even though the code for it to be set to 1 gets executed.

My Program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import time

exittime = 0
def lop():
  while (1):
  if (exittime == 1):
     print("Thread Exiting...")
     return
  print("I am a thread!\n")
  time.sleep(1)

def ask():
   temp = input("Press Enter to continue...")
   if (temp == "100"):
      exittime = 1
      print("Exiting...")

t = threading.Thread(target = ask)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
a = threading.Thread(target = lop)
a.daemon = True
a.start()
```

Output:

```
>>> Press Enter to continue...I am a thread!
100
pressed enter!1
100! Exiting...
I am a thread!
2
I am a thread!
3
print(exittime)
0
```

Why is my thread not working on its on with its loop and instead waiting for the other thread?
And why is exittime not set to 1 after correctly writing 100 and getting the "Exiting..." output?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your function ask(), you need to add the line ‘global exittime’ at the beginning of the function. That allows you to modify the global variable. Moreover, you want to join the 2 threads  at the end, since your main thread may finish before these 2 child threads.

Comment: Thanks a ton Tim! Second Problem solved. Do you have any Idea why the Thread with the "lop" function doesn't loop until i pressed Enter for the "ask" function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a python version problem or even IDLE problem with threading. You can use

```
try:
    ...code...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ...exit...
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

The lop function runs fine for me even when I didn't press enter. This can be seen from the output

```
Press Enter to continue...I am a thread!
I am a thread!
I am a thread!
I am a thread!
```

before I entered `100`.

The code I used is below. If you are running in console, `join()` doesn't make a difference.

```
import threading
import time

exittime = 0
def lop():
    while (1):
        if (exittime == 1):
            print("Thread Exiting...")
            return
        print("I am a thread!\n")
        time.sleep(1)

def ask():
    global exittime
    temp = input("Press Enter to continue...")
    if (temp == "100"):
        exittime = 1
        print("Exiting...")

t = threading.Thread(target = ask)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
a = threading.Thread(target = lop)
a.daemon = True
a.start()
t.join()
a.join()
```

Output:

```
Press Enter to continue...I am a thread!
I am a thread!
I am a thread!
I am a thread!
>? 100
Exiting...
Thread Exiting...
```

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.3 on Windows, and for me - using the IDLE - it's still not working. Maybe i missed some Settings or Version Updates?

Comment: I’m using 3.6.8. That could be the difference.

Comment: You can also get rid of the ask thread entirely and use a try/except KeyboardInterupt to terminate your lop process.

Comment: Actually could be a problem with IDLE. Lots of posts about that. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168686/python-threading-issue-raw-input-blocks-thread-runaway-thread

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will update to 3.6.8 or even 3.7 soon, and will use the try/except to stop the loop. Could you maybe state the version problems in your answer so that i can accept it? Thanks!